# Python/Statsmodels - Vector autoregression endog

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, statsmodels

I'm trying to run a VAR using `statsmodels` library and apparently my endog format is wrong. Tried a few different things but I can't find out how to solve it.

I'm running the following code:

```
def VAR_run(pred_frame,targetframe):

    #preparing the dates
    dates=pred_frame.index

    # preparing target
    targetmatrix=targetframe.as_matrix()

    # preparing pred_frame
    predmatrix=pred_frame.as_matrix()

    #creating endog
    timeseries=(predmatrix,targetmatrix)

    model=VAR((timeseries),dates=dates)
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
File "/Users/file.py", line 1198, in M_pred_frame
VAR_run(pred_frame,targetframe)
File "/file.py", line 1156, in VAR_run
model=VAR((timeseries),dates=dates)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/vector_ar/var_model.py", line 334, in __init__
raise ValueError("Only gave one variable to VAR")
ValueError: Only gave one variable to VAR
```

Can anyone enlighten my journey?

---

**EXTRA INFO**

`pred_frame` is originally a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
            Value  lag1  2lag  3lag  4lag  5lag  6lag  7lag  8lag  9lag
Date                                                                      
...
2015-12-01   1.01  0.82  0.54  0.22  0.62  0.79  0.74  0.71  1.32  1.22   
2016-01-01   0.96  1.01  0.82  0.54  0.22  0.62  0.79  0.74  0.71  1.32   
2016-02-01   1.27  0.96  1.01  0.82  0.54  0.22  0.62  0.79  0.74  0.71
```

`targetframe` is also originally a pandas `DataFrame` like this:

```
            Tgt
Date            
...
2015-10-01  0.54
2015-11-01  0.82
2015-12-01  1.01
2016-01-01  0.96
2016-02-01  1.27
```

When turned into arrays they look like this:

```
targetmatrix = [[  nan]
                [ 1.18]
                [ 0.5 ]
                [ 0.51]
                ...]

predmatrix= ...[  1.27         0.96         1.01       ...,  -2.14865885  -2.14865885
            -3.19355784]
            [         nan          nan          nan ..., -18.13211803  -2.14865885
            -2.14865885]
            [         nan          nan          nan ...,          nan          nan
            nan]]


dates = DatetimeIndex(['1958-04-01', '1958-05-01', '1958-06-01', '1958-07-01',
                       '1958-08-01', '1958-09-01', '1958-10-01', '1958-11-01',
                       '1958-12-01', '1959-01-01',
                       ...
                       '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01',
                       '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01',
                       '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', length=697, freq='MS')
```

About the shapes:

```
targetmatrix.shape = (230, 1)
predmatrix.shape = (697, 1920)
dates.shape=(697,)
```

Your help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

The `statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR` model is meant for multivariate time series as illustrated [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/vector_ar.html). So the input needs to be at least `.shape=(T, 2)`.

There are various other methods for univariate time series analysis avaiable ([see docs)](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html#univariate-autogressive-processes-ar). These accept 1d inputs (or `.shape=(T, 1)`).

Comment: Are you familiar with another Statsmodels method that behaves similarly to VAR or VARMAX and enables you to use exogenous variable as well? (and still accept 1d inputs as you mentioned in the answer)